# Find all repeating subsequence in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am not proficient in algorithm design but was asked this question in one of the job interview. My solution was naive one with heavy complexity but can this be done in shorter time.

Given an array of integers find all the sub sequence of that array which repeats in array. Print sub sequence and then start index and end end index of all their occurrence.

```
e.g 1,0,1,9,5,1,9,5,1
```

Here it should print

```
1,9,5

3:5 6:8

9,5,1

4:6 7:9

1,9

3:4 6:7

5,1

5:6 8:9

9,5

4:5 7:8
```

My solution was to start from `Arr[0]` till `Arr[N/2 -1]` and check if it repeats then do reduced end index by 1 and keep on checking if it repeats.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about contiguous or non-contiguous subsequences? Should they be adjacent to each other or not? `1` is repeated several times in your sample array, but is absent in your sample output (it is definitely sub-sequence and it is repeated).

Comment: not a friendly interview question - it is mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about contiguous subarrays, instead of subsequences that are not necessarily contiguous. Your solution is O(n^3). You can use a suffix tree, which allows you to find the repeating subarray in O(n).

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-tree-application-3-longest-repeated-substring/

Comment: Substring and subsequence is completely different.OP is asking about printing subsequence.

Comment: @Shan: "subsequence" is indeed the word the OP uses, but based on the example s/he gives, s/he means "substring".

Comment: To find repeating (possibly non-contiguous) subsequences, I would use an algorithm like [PrefixSpan](https://github.com/chuanconggao/PrefixSpan-py).